# SQL Server : complex Joins for reporting

Tags: sql-server, database, report

I am writing a query for a banking scenario. The query lists the number of employees working, the amount of customers served, the total loan amount, and the total account amount at a particular bank branch.

The tables are designed like this:

[image: Table Design]

Every branch has employees assigned to it, every bank account is assigned to a branch, every loan is assigned to a branch. A customer can have both a loan and an account at the same branch but should only count as 1 customer served. A customer can have accounts/loans at different banks and should count customer as one customer per bank.

The desired output would look like:

[image: Desired Output]

I honestly have no idea where to start and any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works:

```
SELECT b.BranchID BranchID, 
    COUNT(e.empID) NumEmployees, 
    COUNT(c.customerID) NumCustomers, 
    SUM(ISNULL(l.balance,0)) [Total Load Amount], 
    SUM(ISNULL(a.balance,0)) [Total Account Amount]
FROM Branch b
    JOIN Employee e ON b.branchID = e.branchid
    JOIN Loan l ON l.branchID = b.branchID
       AND l.empID = e.empID
    JOIN Account a ON a.branchID = b.branchID
       AND a.empID = e.empID
    JOIN Customer c ON c.customerID = l.customerID
       AND c.customerID = a.customerID
GROUP BY b.branchID
```

Comment: Hey Bjones. Unfortunately it did not work. No results. Thanks though!

Comment: @SeanGreaves Are there `NULL` values in your data?

Comment: The only NULL values would be in enddate and closedate for account/loan

Comment: @SeanGreaves I added `ISNULL` to the `SUM` columns. Maybe ?

Comment: came back with the same results. I'll keep tinkering with it